# Differences between Excel Solver & PuLP solver in python,

Tags: python, solver, pulp

Solver in excel is more efficient like PuLP Solver, or I made some mistake. Please can you help me?

Python PuLP (Not correct results):

```py
from pulp import *
p = (120, 72, 80)
o = (0.85, 0.85, 0.80)

lp= LpProblem("Linka1_2_3", LpMaximize)
print("OBJECTIVE1: ",lp.objective)

x1 = LpVariable(name="Time:Line1Ref1",lowBound=0)
x2 = LpVariable(name='Time:Line2Ref1',lowBound=0)

print("Constrains: ",lp.constraints)

# Objective function
lp += lpSum(102*x1 + 61.2*x2)

# Constrains
lp += 102*x1 <= 500
lp += 61.2 *x2  <=500
lp += 102*x1 + 61.2*x2  <=500
lp += x1 <= 3.5
lp += x2 <= 3.5

status = lp.solve()
print("Status:", status, "   ---1:optimal, 2:not solved, 3:infeasible, 4:unbounded, 5:undef")

#Print solution
i=0
for var in lp.variables():
    print(f" ",var, "=", value(var), "Tzn. ",((p[i]*o[i]))," PxO a cas straveny", value(var)*(p[i]*o[i])," pcs")
    i += 1
print("OPT =", value(lp.objective))
```

```
Result:
Time:Line1Ref1 = 2.8019608 Tzn.  102.0  PxO a cas straveny 285.8000016  pcs
Time:Line2Ref1 = 3.5 Tzn.  61.199999999999996  PxO a cas straveny 214.2  pcs

Time X1 + X2 = 6.3019....
```

Correct result should be: `5.836601` like in Excel (6.3 is too high & not correct solution)

Where in code I have fault?

Here is XLSX table with formulas:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ďakujem za názor. Potrebujem vedieť prečo pulp nevypočita spravne riešenie. Správne riešenie je x1=3.5 a x2=2.33?  Pulp x1=2.8 a x2=3.5, prečo to pulp nedokáže?

Comment: Reinderien 102= 120 * 0.85, its only easy formula.
Thank you for your comment, but in both systems (excel, python) are the same. 
Objective function in both is: 102 * x1 + 61.2 * x2, 
Constrains are:
x1<=3.5, 
x2<=3.5, 
102 * x1 <=500, 
61.2 * x2 <=500, 
102 * x1 + 61.2 * x2 <=500
Optimal solution is x1 = 3.5  & x2 =2.336601 based on excel solution, 
but in python PuLP give result x1=2.801961  & x2 = 3.5.
Why and where in python code I made fault? Do you know ?

Comment: @Reinderien - I have changed question. Now, You can check it. Thank you for your cooperation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is under-determined, so there are multiple solutions that produce the optimal value of 500 right at its bound. PuLP is more than capable of producing such a solution. More importantly, though, you've mis-constructed your problem, and need to replace your constraints and objective based on what it is you really want.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pulp

idx = ('Lin1Ref1', 'Lin2Ref1')
ConstrainsX12 = (3.5, 3.5)
ConstrainsX = (*ConstrainsX12, max(ConstrainsX12))
X12 = [
    pulp.LpVariable(
        name=f'X_{i}', cat=pulp.LpContinuous,
        lowBound=0, upBound=bound)
    for i, bound in zip(idx, ConstrainsX12)
]
X = (*X12, pulp.lpSum(X12))
P = (120, 72)
O = (0.85, 0.85)
PxO = [pi*ji for pi, ji in zip(P, O)]
XxPxO12 = [xi*poi for xi, poi in zip(X, PxO)]
XxPxO = (*XxPxO12, pulp.lpSum(XxPxO12))
Constrains_formula = (500,)*3

lp = pulp.LpProblem(name='Line1_2_3', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
lp.setObjective(X[-1])

lp.addConstraint(XxPxO[-1] == Constrains_formula[-1])

print(lp)
status = lp.solve()
assert status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=(*idx, 'B4 + B5:'),
    data={
        'X': [pulp.value(x) for x in X],
        'P': (*P, ''),
        'O': (*O, 'SUMRef1:'),
        'PxO': (*PxO, ''),
        'Solv: XxPxO': [pulp.value(p) for p in XxPxO],
        'Constrains formula': Constrains_formula,
        'Constrains[X]': ConstrainsX,
    },
)
pd.options.display.width = 200
pd.options.display.max_columns = 9
print(df)
```

```
                 X    P         O    PxO  Solv: XxPxO  Constrains formula  Constrains[X]
Lin1Ref1  3.500000  120      0.85  102.0        357.0                 500            3.5
Lin2Ref1  2.336601   72      0.85   61.2        143.0                 500            3.5
B4 + B5:  5.836601       SUMRef1:               500.0                 500            3.5
```

Comment: Thank you, for your support but x1 is lower than x2. X1+x2 is 6.3. In Excel is x1+x2=5.8 and it is better.

Comment: It's not better. If it were better, that would be represented in the objective. The only objective is a sum running up to 500.

Comment: And what is it. We have 2 production lines. On first is output 102 pcs/hour. Second output is 61.2 pcs/h. We have only 3.5 hours for production on both lines. Demandice for production is 500pcs. x1 & x2 are spend time in line. Therefore x1+x2 is important.

Comment: If it's important, represent it in an objective; otherwise it does not matter at all to the solution

Comment: Could you set up objective function to result will 5.8 hours? I didn't have to in Excel.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Why 5.8 hours specifically? There's really nothing saying that that's a better solution. Do you want to drop your current XxPxo objective and replace it with one that minimizes x1+x2? If you do, x1+x2 will end up being less than 5.8.

Comment: 500pcs is necessary. Only all want produce quickly. Why in Excel it is native.

Comment: Then your entire formulation is wrong. Don't have the number of pieces as a maximization objective; have it as an equality constraint and minimize the sum of x.

Comment: I dont know how and what i need change.

Comment: Like that - change to minimization; minimize x1+x2; only have one equality constraint.

Comment: It looks very good. Thank you. I was confused (objective, constrains .....)